# Shared line circuit example using CMOS-N and CMOS-P transistors

Tags: voltage

I'm a student and I would like to find somewhere an image consisting of a simple electrical sheme containing a shared line with CMOS-N and CMOS-P transistors.

Comment: What does "shared line" mean? What is a "CMOS-N" or "CMOS-P" transistor? Do you mean n-channel and p-channel MOSFETs?

Comment: It is for an assignment, and yes, i meant p-channel and n-channel MOSFETs.